# How to list all files that are in GCP bucket behind an external load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcp-load-balancer

I have a load balancer with 2 buckets as a backend. Let's call them `bucket1` and `bucket2`. The structure of these buckets is similar and looks like this:

- `dir1`
- `dir1/subdir1`
- `dir1/subdir2`
- ...
- `dir2/subdir1`
- ...

Every `subdirx` has multiple files.

I want to use the load balancer that has a static IP to:

1. List all the files in the bucket (full paths)
2. Get a file

Any idea how to achieve (1)? How should I structure the rules and the paths of my LoadBalancer? Any help is more than appreciated. Thanks in advance.